# Find all sub directories and long paths

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find every folder that contains a `.fbi2` file for processing later on in the script. But I am running into an issue where long paths are causing the script to terminate.

My code is as follows:

```
require "find"
def find_case_directories(search_directories)
    case_paths = []
    search_directories.each do |search_directory|
        Find.find(search_directory) do |path|
          if FileTest.directory?(path)
            unless Dir["#{path}/case.fbi2"].empty?
              case_paths << "#{path}"
              Find.prune # Don't look any further into this directory.
            else
              next
            end
          end
        end
    end
    case_paths
end
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Script was cancelled by the user.
Errno::ESRCH: No such process - D:/Cases/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/20180914_Import_01/20180914_Import_01/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/Tranche 2/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>.MSG
                           lstat at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:931
                   block in find at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/find.rb:51
                           catch at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1114
                   block in find at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/find.rb:48
                            each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734
                            find at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/find.rb:43
  block in find_case_directories at <script>:76
                            each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734
           find_case_directories at <script>:75
                          <main> at <script>:98
```

I have checked the path the script mentions, and it is indeed over 255 characters in length.

How can I recursively walk directories to find all folders that contain a `.fbi2` file, and store them in an array?

Comment: What file system are you using? NTFS or FAT32?

Comment: We are using NTFS

Comment: Usually, NTFS does length related problems. One other thing, Did you handled this case? `if search_directory == '.' or search_directory == '..'
    next
  end`

Comment: You might need to handle current/parent directory entries specially, or set `ignore_error: true`. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html